# Wordpress - pages have low text-HTML ratio

Tags: wordpress, seo

I have a wordpress site and I have 5 pages with low text-HTML ratio, this is for category pages, author page and the home page. I have removed all unnecessary plugins to reduce code and it got rid of one (I had 6 before). I understand removing comments and spaces between lines of code will help. I am just wondering if there is a plugin that will do this, or what would be the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SEO, the text-to-HTML ratio shouldn't matter as long as the content doesn't have unnecessary bloat or the additional code causes the page to slow down excessively. See [additional details here](https://www.woorank.com/en/blog/are-text-to-html-ratios-important).

You could try using a [minify plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fast-velocity-minify/) if you would like to reduce page-size.